# Monoidal categories: strictness from coherence

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, monoidal-categories

A version of Mac Lane's Coherence Theorem states that every formal diagram (i.e., a diagram that involves only the associativity isomorphism, the unit isomorphisms, their inverses, identity morphisms, the monoidal product, and composites) commute.

From this version, how to deduce the other version that states that every monoidal category can be strictified via an adjoint equivalence consisting of strong monoidal functors?

I believe that the [opposite question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3480156) has already been answered by [jgon](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/90543). However, I cannot find in the literature the direction of interest to me. And I'm afraid I have no clue.

Comment: A sketch: for a monoidal category $C$, define $S$ with objects the finite sequences of objects of $C$, and $\otimes$ to be concatenation, the arrows $(a_1,\dots, a_n)\to (b_1,\dots, b_n)$ correspond to arrows $a_1\otimes \dots \otimes a_n\to b_1\otimes \dots \otimes b_m$ of $C$. I think you can find details in one or more papers of Leinster, for example (maybe for *bicategories* instead of monoidal categories).

Comment: @Berci Thanks for the hint! I found it in Leinster's *Basic Bicategories* although it is quite abstract there. But now I'm curious about how your sketch generalizes to bicategories (instead of monoidal categories). In other words, if, in your sketch, $C$ were a bicategory, how would would define the bicategory $S$?

Comment: We take sequences of *composable arrows*

Comment: @Berci So $S$ has the same $0$-cells than $C$; The $1$-cells of $S$ are sequences of composable $1$-cells of $C$. What about the 2-cells?

Comment: As in my comment, they correspond to $2$-cells of $C$, $a_1\dots a_n\to b_1 \dots  b_m$. It's exactly the coherence theorem needed to prove it's a well-defined 2-category.